# Handle buffer overflow from 3rd party dll

Tags: c++, dll, buffer-overflow

In my project I make use of an older 3rd party DLL that is not going to be updated. It is used to decompress data. It decompresses the data and puts the result into a buffer that was passed to it.

The problem is that a buffer overflow can occur if the resulting data is put into a buffer that has **not allocated enough space.** This buffer size is an int32 value prepended to the compressed data. If an incorrect buffer size is there, then a buffer overflow occurs resulting in heap corruption.

How can you recover from this? I can detect **if** a buffer overflow occurred, but only after the decompression function from the DLL is called.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What dll do you use? If it's so easy to crash why wouldn't you switch to other?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk Because it is the only one available that handles this compression format.

Comment: Can't you use other? What dll do you use? (name+version)

Comment: No there is no other. It is xcompress from the Xbox 360 SDK. (Not public)

Comment: Can't you check does decompressed data for example x2 isn't greater than buffer size? You can always do some reverse-engineering to this dll

Comment: Put try/catch around the call to detect.

Comment: @stark I don't think old library would throw you an error.

Comment: @stark It doesnt throw any exceptions

Comment: The buffer size is actually almost always at least twice as large as the decompressed data (because it goes through two rounds of decompression). However, third party software often produces incorrect (smaller) buffer sizes which causes heap corruption in MY software. I want to avoid this.

Comment: @mrg95 -- Please give us a link to the documentation of this function.  It is hard to believe that there is no way a user can't get the size in some way before calling the function.  Many API's have two modes, one mode is to call the API function with a "NULL" or special argument to only return the size required.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There is no documentation, it's not a public dll. The decompressed size is RETURNED from the decompression function. However, it will have already been put into the buffer. I'm not sure if there is another mode I can switch to

Comment: I would pass a NULL as the buffer, and see what happens.  Also, is there an "out" argument or return value that tells you what the size actually is?  If not, then that function really shouldn't be used, as it is basically useless for any real work.  An "out" value would at least give you the chance of resizing your buffer to the correct size (if the size you chose is too large).

Comment: Yes there is a `pDestSize` argument that returns the actual size.

Comment: So what you could do is allocate something very large, and on return, resize the buffer according to what `pDestSize` returns.  Also, it gives me the impression that you **can** call the function with a NULL argument just to get the `pDestSize` on return, and then call it again with a buffer of that size.  That's the way many API's work that deal with this situation.

Comment: Just passed NULL and it crashed on the decompression function call. So no, guess it doesn't support NULL arguments.

Comment: Then I guess allocate something very large (better to use `std::vector<char> buf(some_large_value)`, pass a pointer to the first element, and on return `buf.resize(returned_size)` or swap out to a new vector.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why std::vector<char> with a large size is better than a regular char array?

Comment: 1) Arrays cannot be resized.  2) A `vector` knows it's own size, while arrays have no concept of their own size.  3) Arrays decay to pointers when passed, vector does not decay (related to item 2).

Comment: Also, performance is an issue since this gets called thousands of times. Can I expect to see slowdowns by using a vector? Also, the decompression function argument for the buffer is `void *pDestination`

Comment: Please measure, and measure only release, optimized builds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What value does *pDestSize have before your call?

Comment: The size of the result buffer. *incorrect* size I should say.

Comment: So you set *pDestSize to the actual buffer size before the call?

Comment: Yes but like I said, I dont know the actual buffer size u til after it was called. The buffer size is an int32 value prepended to the compressed data, but I'm trying to handle cases when that is incorrect.

Comment: You should know the size of your own buffer.

Comment: You have failed to understand the problem I am facing. I am loading user generated content where the possibility of an invalid buffer size could be provided (And has been provided). Normally, I would prevent an overflow from ever happening, however, the usage takes place in a 3rd party dll that has no checks. Therefore, I am asking for a technique I could implement to safely use this dll's bad handling. You're asking me to assume that the given buffer size of decompressed data be 100% correct in every case. Quite foolish to make an assumption like that. Please read the previous comments. -_-

Answer (score 0):

The only real solution is to make your buffer larger than any *possible* result size.  If you don't do this, then by your description of the function, once you call the function, heap corruption may have already occurred.